# Deleting children when parent is deleted?

Tags: lotus-notes

**Q:** When a document is marked/unmarked for deletion, and this document is a parent of child documents, is there a way to also mark/unmark its children for deletion?

I know I can hook into `DatabaseScript:OnDocumentDelete()` and delete the documents immediately, but that's not what my client wants (obviously, because done that way you couldn't undelete them). Alternatively, I could implement my own "trash" functionality (to support undeletion), but it seems to me that this should be built-in.

**Q:** Put another way, is there a "softer" alternative to `NotesDocument.Delete()` which will merely *(un)mark* a document for deletion rather than deleting it straight away?

In any case, this cannot be the first time anyone's had need of this; however, I have not been able to find useful resources on the Internet (possibly because it's rather tricky to search for).

Help?

Comment: I guess, you will have to handle it by yourselves. There is not such a function to undelete response document while undeleting parent.

Comment: Of course, soft deletion function is built-in. You just have to enable it in the database properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality is not built in so you would have to create your own mechanism.

The underlying question is whether there is an event to hook into that is triggered when a user unmarks a document for deletion.  I don't believe there is.  Perhaps in the C API.

You could alternatively prevent child docs from being deleted if they have a parent by handling the ondocumentdelete event and checking each doc to see if it is a response doc.

Comment: Well, the method `DbScript:OnDocumentDelete()` _is_ in fact balanced by `DbScript:OnDocumentUndelete()` - but that only gets me half-way there: If I do intercept the delete-event and delete the children, they'd be gone if the user wants to undelete. Ideally I'd want to hook into these two methods, but there is nothing "softer" than `NotesDocument.Delete()`, which does not correspond to the "deletion mark" but deletes the document straight away.

Comment: Did you check the Soft Deletions function, as I mentioned in previous comment? It's built-in functionality and it works like trash folder in e-mail.
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21091152

Comment: Yes, thank you. But it doesn't affect child documents -- sure, you can soft delete the children, or the parent, and that works as described -- but soft deleting a parent does not _also_ soft delete its children, and that's what I'm after. I hope I'm explaining myself well enough. :-)

Comment: Yes, and as I said before, there is no such a built-in functionality for this. You can do two things. 1. Use the more difficult way and handle OnDocumentDelete/OnDocumentUndelete. 2. Or prohibit users deletion in ACL at all and create your own script deletion action with button in a view. When user tries to delete doc manually, just call msgbox to tell him to use a button Delete.

Comment: Ah, now I understand your first comment more fully. Silly me. I'll probably go for option 3: let users normally-delete the parent documents, and do an occasional sweep for orphaned child documents.

Comment: That is a wise idea. I do it the same way.